# Android Canvas Not Displaying

Tags: java, android

I'm making a simple painting app, and it's my first time using the canvas. I already have the SurfaceView in my layout xml, and the id is correct. Anyways, here is my code:

```
package com.example.paint;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.graphics.Canvas;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.SurfaceHolder;
import android.view.SurfaceView;

public class Paint extends Activity {
/** Called when the activity is first created. */

SurfaceView v;
SurfaceHolder holder;
Canvas c;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    v = (SurfaceView) findViewById(R.id.svDraw);
    holder = v.getHolder();

    while (true) {
        try {
            Thread.sleep(1000);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        if (!holder.getSurface().isValid())
            continue;

        c = holder.lockCanvas();
        c.drawARGB(255, 0, 255, 0);
        holder.unlockCanvasAndPost(c);
    }
}
}
```

Thanks.

Comment: and what is the problem?

Comment: Your app will ANR because you block the UI thread forever in `onCreate`. Have a look at the [LunarLander](http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/LunarLander/src/com/example/android/lunarlander/index.html) Api demo for an example how it could work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to remove the `while(true)`, its an infinite loop that prevents anything from happening.

The drawing code belongs in the `onDraw` method of your `View` that contains your canvas object